# Error al agregar entity data model en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

estoy agregando un entity model a mi proyecto c#, pero estoy teniendo un problema con el asistente, no se que tendria que actualizar para que pueda continuar con la siguiente ventana que es seleccionar las tablas, pero no he podido pasar por que me genera este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué gestor de base de datos es? ¿Qué versión? ¿Algo especial a recalcar?